# Fondo not working in Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: lubuntu, desktop-background, flatpak

I am running Lubuntu 18.04 on my old laptop. It works great even thought the hardware is almost 8 years old.

I recently installed Fondo, the desktop background changing app, from Flathub. The link is- [Fondo on Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.calo001.fondo)

I can start the program. Usually, Fondo shows you a bunch of wallpapers to choose from, and you just select one of them to be your desktop background. But when I click on a wallpaper, nothing happens. In have tried it multiple times, without any success. Someone please help me with this.

I also run Linux Mint 19 on other laptop. I installed Fondo from Flathub there as well. But it works very smoothly on Mint 19.

Comment: It maybe related to https://github.com/calo001/fondo/issues/52 (*but I could be wrong*).  The working on Mint info isn't useful without the desktop (which I suspect is why it works there, ie. you're not using LXDE on Mint)

Comment: Yes, I think it's the same bug actually. I am using the Cinnamon DE on Linux Mint 19.

Comment: All I can suggest is you add your info to the github issue describing your situation & how it impacts you. It may help it get fixed; however Lubuntu has moved away from LXDE (to LXQt which finally reached prime-time in 18.10 having started years before) and try another screen changing solution.  (Security fixes are still made for Lubuntu 18.04 until 2021-April)

Comment: Thank you @guiverc. I just reported the issue in Github.